# JQuery attr always returns the same value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Guys i have post list where each post have own ID. I want with jquery to get that id from custom attribute. Problem is when i try to debug i get all time the some value.

This is html table that i list from database with PHP. Each post have specific ID.

```
Name      |    id 
-------------------
Post 1    |   188
Post 2    |   189
Post 3    |   190

<i id="like" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" data-id="<?=$post->post_id;?>"></i> Like
```

So when i try to get value from **data-id** script all time return **188** number. When click on Post 1, post 2, post 3 all time value is 188!!! Whay ?

Here is JQuery:

```
isPostLiked: function() {
    var isLiked = false;
    var likeText = $("#like");
    var itemId = likeText.attr("data-id");

    // debug 
    Post.postLikeBtn.click(function() {
      console.log(itemId);
    });

    //$.ajax({
    //    type: "post",
    //    url: baseurl + "/like/isLikedAjaxAction/"
    //});

    if (isLiked == true) {
      likeText.css("color", "red");
    }
},
```

Comment: You never change `itemId`.

Comment: `Post.postLikeBtn` is `$("button#post_like_btn")`

Comment: How does `post_like_btn` is linked to `like`? You should share HTML also.

Comment: why the down vote? I posted before the other guy.  Hover over the "answered 23 mins ago" text to see the actual timestamp.

Comment: @Ivke I work damn hard for these internet points LOL

Comment: bro i dont down vote u.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are generating HTML in a loop. Remember Identifiers in HTML must be **unique**, you can use CSS class then [Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) can be used. Modify you HTML as

```
<i class="like glyphicon glyphicon-heart" data-id="<?=$post->post_id;?>"></i> Like
```

Change click handlers and fetch ids using the current element context i.e. `this`

```
$('.like').click(function(){
    var id= $(this).data('id');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Every element must have a unique id attribute.  You cannot have more than one element with an id of "like."  Try something like this instead:

```
<i class="like glyphicon glyphicon-heart" data-id="<?=$post->post_id;?>"></i> Like
```

Then define do this to set your callback:

```
$('.like').click(function() { /* your code here */ });
```

Comment: Yep you answered earlier than me. +1